# Each loop not showing same result as console log

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to display the results of what was keyed into the `<input>` field.

This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btn_copy").click(function(){
        $("input").each(function () {
            $("#final").html($(this).val());
            console.log($(this).val());
         });
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="excel_table">
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Excel Data</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <button id="btn_copy">Copy Over</button>

    <div id="final"></div>
```

Console log is showing me my desired results and when I try to display it out, it is showing me only the last input field.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how I can try to display all my results, just like how console log is doing?

Also, can someone please let me know why does it work on console but not on html?

ps: the snippet hides the display, so please expand the snippet to make it fullscreen.

Comment: `$("#final").html($(this).val());` <-- You're overwritting the previous value, if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you dont add each new inputs value to #final. It gets overwritten with each loop iteration. Try something like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btn_copy").click(function(){
        $("input").each(function () {
            $("#final").html($("#final").html() + $(this).val());
            console.log($(this).val());
         });
    });
  });
```

Comment: `$("#final").append($(this).val())` maybe?

Comment: @freedomn-m I guess you could also use append.

Comment: Hi @Alex, thanks it sorts of work, just that, say if I were to type 1, 2 , 3 and the next round I type 1, 2 , 4, the results are like 1,2,3,1,2,4. Hmm shouldn't the display clear? Why is it still storing the older results?

Comment: @Gosi are you telling it to remove the older results? :)

Comment: Yup @Alex, would that be possible? I tried adding `$("#final").html = ""` , but it didn't work.

Comment: @Gosi of course it would. You got the right idea but the wrong syntax. Right after the click, right before the loop type: `$("#final").html('')`. Your code doesnt work because `.html =` would be setting a property, but `$()` creates a jQuery object that does not have that property. Use the jQuery function `.html()`

Comment: @Alex Oh my, that worked, haha thanks man, learnt something new! Cheers, yup I added it after click and before loop and the idea makes sense!

Comment: @Gosi great to hear! Next up I suggest you have a little read on the difference between vanilla javascripts `.innerHtml = ''` and jQuerys `.html()` function ;)

Comment: @Alex noted, yup will do that. I get really mixed up with these syntax, I need to read the jquery documentations again. It is clearly written there.